# how to read mail from the system locally (with ruby)

Tags: ruby, email, postfix-mta

After some adventure I managed to install and configure [Postfix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix) on my server.  I confirmed that it works, I was able to send myself some mail and got it under `~/Maildir/new`

I would like to use ruby mail gem to slurp it in.  github has directions on how to set this up:

```
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '',
                          :password   => '',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end
```

however, I would like to parse mail on the same server I will be receiving it.  Also I will be the only person receiving email on the server.  I was wondering if I could simply pass `Mail` defaults the path to new email folder (`~/Maildir/new` in this case) and read it that way.  Then I would parse and load it into the database and remove the email files.  Could I set up ruby mail to parse email by just giving it the path?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I think it's a better way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Instead of having postfix deliver the message, have it pipe the message to your program (see `man aliases`).  Then you can handle the message with the mail gem in your program by doing `Mail.new(STDIN.read)`.  This saves you the trouble of dealing dealing with maildirs/deleting messages/etc.